# What type of plane is this?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Looks like a biplane with an inline engine.

Time frame is probably pre December 1941.

As a second question: Does anyone know what the shield shaped emblem would be, i.e., what squadron, etc.?

[image]

Comment: welcome to aviation.SE. could you tell us which country is the photo from?

Comment: Inline engine?  It could be a V24 :)

Comment: What is the source for the photo?

Answer (score 4):

Part 1

I submit the Curtiss P-1 Hawk, A US Army Air Corp Pursuit aircraft that entered service in 1923.

See Wiki: [Curtiss P-1 Hawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss_P-1_Hawk)

[Similar angle of Museum example](https://www.flickr.com/photos/danielmennerich/25675796144)

My evidence is the following:

1. Similar engine cover shape and air inlet design
2. Similar parasol wing layout

Part 2.

I do not have any suggestion for the origin of the emblem, other than to look for images of the markings of the various units post 1923, The Wiki lists squadrons that received the P-1.